# Further opportunities with an ASP.NET Project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, project, web-deployment, publish

I recently finished a personal web application I had created for my uni. It's mine now to do with as I want. I wrote it on Visual Studio using ASP.Net, CSS, and C#. (I had originally written the first few pages in HTML and PHP, but due to a problem with my computer's inability to run XAMPP, the PHP pages weren't running as required so I redid it on Visual Studio)

The project's initial functionalities (uploading media and documentation, and login and user registration) are there and the pages work, and I plan to proactively work on it to add more features and make it more dynamic and versatile.

However, I have a question, what can I do with it now? Is there a platform (maybe Stackoverflow itself?) that I can upload the project as a whole on to add it to my technical portfolio? or maybe another such action I could do to upload or publish it to add it to my list of things done as a reference for recruiters, or as part of my project history for graduate school?